# Under which circumstances will a C Linker eliminate unused volatile symbols?

Tags: c, linker

I am using a very specific toolchain (SHARC DSP Processor from Analog Devices) and I would like to get a better understanding of my compiler/linker.

I have somewhere a volatile global variable:

```
 volatile long foo;
```

This variable is not used and not referenced in my code but I want to preserve it in my final executable (don't ask me why, the sad truth is sad).

I usually link my project with the `-e` option. It tells the linker to remove dead code from the executable. I initially thought no compilers would dare remove any global variable especially if these symbols are declared as volatile. Unfortunately it does.

Then I found a very specific pragma `#pragma retain_name` which tell the linker to keep a symbol even though it is never used.

I would like to know if such situation can be found in some ISO/POSIX standards. I always though neither the compiler or the linker would make any assumptions on volatile symbols. And thus, no compilers would ever try to remove a dead volatile variable or function from the final executable.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see why the variable being `volatile` would prevent it from being optimized away?

Comment: volatile specify that the variable will be accessed outside of the compiler's knowledge so yes, a conforming compiler should **never** remove a volatile variable. It can't even reorder operations involving it.

Comment: @bolov I agree with your for the compiler, but can we make the same assumption for the linker?

Comment: I never asked myself this question. I can only assume yes. In the sens of my previous comment, the definition of *compiler* includes the linker.

Comment: It may be possible it is a bug or a non-conforming behavior of your compiler toolchain.

Comment: @bolov, I agree, and that's what I want to point out before asking Analog Devices.

Comment: @NPE AFIK that's what `volatile` means: **don't touch**: don't optimize, don't reorder, don't remove (for the reasons described in my first comment).

Comment: That's not really what `volatile` means.  It means that when parsing code that accesses the variable, it must follow the exact semantics of the syntax, and cannot, for example, convert `int x = volatile_int + volatile_int;` into `int x = volatile_int << 1;` -- it must keep two memory accesses to `volatile_int`.  But if the code never accesses the variable, the compiler (and linker) are under no obligation to do anything about keeping it.

Comment: Just to clarify my earlier comment: when I say "optimized away" I specifically mean "optimized away if it's unused".

Comment: the linker won't know about volatile. That information goes away once compiled.  You could use the tricks already mentioned or use a linker script with (toolchain dependend) commands to inline (and keep) an otherwise unused variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one standard for C is the K&R book, there is not much to say about `volatile` except that it is mentioned a few times and is said to be related to optimization.

In Appendix A.8.2 Type Specifiers, it says this:

> Types may also be qualified, to indicate special properties of the
>   objects being declared.  type-qualifier: 
>   const
>   volatile
>   Type qualifiers may appear with any type specifier. A const 
>   object may be initialized, but not thereafter assigned to. 
>   There are no implementation-dependent semantics for volatile objects.  The const
>   and volatile properties are new with the ANSI standard. The purpose of
>   const is to announce objects that may be placed in read-only memory,
>   and perhaps to increase opportunities for optimization. **The purpose of**
>   **volatile is to force an implementation to suppress optimization that
>   could otherwise occur.** For example, for a machine with memory-mapped
>   input/output, a pointer to a device register might be declared as a
>   pointer to volatile, in order to prevent the compiler from removing
>   apparently redundant references through the pointer. **Except that it
>   should diagnose explicit attempts to change const objects, a compiler
>   may ignore these qualifiers.**

Emphasis mine and note what the last paragraph says. It could suggest that the compiler can choose to ignore the `volatile` qualifier anyway.

The compilers will allow volatile variable to remain un-optimized in my experience, even if they are never used.
I'm not so sure about the linkers though. The standard says very little about the linking process.

FWIW my general experience with commercial compilers for embedded targets, is that they sometimes do not comply fully with the standards. I've been using a TI compiler+linker toolchain lately, and let's just say it is really different from what I'm used to with the gcc+ld ports for ARM e.g. ...

**EDIT:**

No of course the K&R book is not the standard. Let's have a look at a real standard, e.g. the ISO C99 standard obtained from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), one paragraph in `Section 6.7.3 Type qualifiers, 6` says:

> An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the
>   implementation or have other unknown side effects. Therefore any expression referring
>   to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine,
>   as described in 5.1.2.3. Furthermore, at every sequence point the value last stored in the
>   object shall agree with that prescribed by the abstract machine, except as modified by the
>   unknown factors mentioned previously.114) **What constitutes an access to an object that
>   has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined**.

Unfortunately I don't think this helps answer the question..

Answer (score 4):

You could make a dummy function with external linkage that uses the variable.

```
long
help_us_keep_foo(void)
{
  return foo;
}
```

Unless you are performing whole-program analysis, this will prevent `foo` from being eliminated.  If you *do* perform whole-program analysis, you can use a trick like the following.

```
int
main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
  if (getenv("PRINT_THE_VALUE_OF_FOO_AT_PROGRAM_STARTUP"))
    printf("Your hovercraft is full of eels, and foo is %ld\n", foo);
  /* Do whatever your program has to do... */
  return 0;
}
```

I have been using a similar trick (inserting harmless print statements that test an exceptionally unlikely condition) in benchmarking code to make sure that the things I wanted to benchmark are not optimized away.

If the situation permits it, you could use a less “visible” trick like assigning `foo = foo` but since it is `volatile`, I'm not sure you can do this safely.

Comment: Addendum: this may be OK on a PC, but in an embedded context (where volatile is probably used most often), do not use print statements lightly. They can hog all kinds of resources, even if never executed. See https://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/04/19/why-i-dont-like-printf/ .

Comment: @Dmitri Thanks for the interesting blog-post. I can well imagine that one might want to decide not to use `printf` and it certainly is a severe security flaw to use an untrusted format string. However, since the format string in the above example is a literal and the code won't be executed anyway, security, performance and stack-usage concerns will be moot. The only remaining valid concern is having to link `printf` in. If this dirty trick is *the only place* in your program where it is used, certainly don't do it. But if your application is using `printf` anyway, one extra usage won't hurt.