# Preventing gcc from discarding a variable just because it is not used

Tags: gcc, linker

Normally I compile with flags that discard all variables that are never used (using -fdata-sections). But sometimes, I need to include a variable into a special section and I want that variable to never be optimized away even if it is not used.

How can I tell gcc linker (using attributes perhaps?) that it can under no circumstances discard a specific variable?

Comment: Try declaring it as volatile see if that helps

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201618/under-which-circumstances-will-a-c-linker-eliminate-unused-volatile-symbols

Comment: gcc [variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes) might help. e.g., `"section"` and `"used"`.